# How does a fixed-effects regression improve on a pooled OLS regression with non-normal residuals, heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation?

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, pooling

I am running a pooled OLS regression as a benchmark model on a panel data set of online forum member activity. The aim of the model is to understand the relationship between exposure to hate speech and its adoption.

The pooled model therefore includes exposure to hate speech the previous month as the independent variable of interest, alongside variables controlling for the number of months spent on the forum and the total number of forum posts. The results of the regression can be seen below:[image]

Analysis of the residual errors from the pooled model suggest that the residual errors are not normally distributed, shown by a heavy-tailed Q-Q plot. While there is also evidence of heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation.

[image].

To improve upon the pooled OLS model I plan on implementing a fixed effects model, controlling for time and entity (forum member) fixed effects via a process of de-meaning. This is done using the PanelOLS package from linear models in python and using robust and clustered standard errors.

Comment: Some of the terminology you use differs strongly between fields, so it would help if you could include more details, including the equation and/or a brief bit of code to explain the model.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I have edited the question slightly to include more detail - hope this helps!

Comment: Well done, and +1. I know this is not common in economics and some other fields, but have you considered partial pooling (via mixed effects models a.k.a. hierarchical models)? In my field this is considered superior to both unpooled and completely pooled models.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How, if at all, does a fixed effects model deal with 'issues' of non normal residual errors, heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation?

Comment: FE models deal with these issues in the ways that any statistical model deals with them....with regression diagnostics. If you want to drill into them, you've got to climb the learning curve. Poke around on CV wrt them. A good primer is *Regression Diagnostics* by Belsey, Kuh and Welsch. Another good ref is Gelman and Hill's *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*.

Comment: Also consider [semiparametric models](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) that do not make distributional assumptions.